# How can I add a min_length argument to django auth's UserCreationForm?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models, django-authentication

If I were defining my own form, it would be so simple to type "min_length=4" to any field. But I'm using UserCreationForm. How can I set a min length?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ( "username", "email" )
```

You can include the `min_length` to the `email` field now I think.

Answer (score 0):

> The forms Emailfield Has two optional arguments for validation, max_length and min_lengh. If provided, these arguments ensure that the string is at most or at least the given length.
>
> > Even while extending/inheriting UserCreationForm the same logic does apply.
>
> Kindly refer to:
>
> ## https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/fields/